# How can a domain be live and available to be directed to an IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, domain

I was just thinking, how can a domain be live and available, all this time we buy a domain to turn on and then we use, but how is the flow? whether to turn on a domain and then use it must always buy the domain name? Or is there a way that we can activate a domain without paying for it? And even though we buy the domain, why after we buy the domain the new domain is active and we can use the domain

An interesting discussion in my opinion.

let's say I want to turn on [wh4ty0utth1nk.org](http://wh4ty0utth1nk.org), but I don't want to get this domain by buying it, maybe all I can do is add the line `127.0.0.1 wh4ty0utth1nk.org` to `/etc/hosts` or `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on my computer, but the domain is only available on the computer I'm using, what I want is that everyone in the world can also access this domain. How and the explanation?

In short, I'd like an explanation of how an unavailable domain can exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that DNS is *hierarchical.* It's not a giant distributed database – it's a collection of privately managed [zones](https://www.cloudflare.com/img/learning/dns/glossary/dns-zone/dns-zone.png), each of which has a specific person or company managing it and setting the rules.

> why after we buy the domain the new domain is active and we can use the domain

A domain begins to "exist" when it's added to the *parent* domain's DNS records. For your `example.org` to become available, the owner of the `org` domain (which is currently PIR) must add the appropriate 'NS' records to their own zone.

(Similarly, once you own `example.org`, *you* can create further subdomains if you want. Several projects do this to give away subdomains for free, which you can use like a "real" domain – "EU.ORG" being one of the oldest examples.)

So when you buy an .org domain from some registrar, that registrar's system immediately contacts the appropriate *registry* – the company that manages the parent domain, which is PIR for .org – and asks them to add NS records for your freshly bought domain.

(The communication between registrars and registries is usually done through the EPP protocol without any human involvement, though I believe it used to be done through email in very distant past.)

> is there a way that we can activate a domain without paying for it?

Only the .org registry can truly "activate" .org domains, because they're the ones managing the actual database for .org – it's just like how only a website's owner can upload files to their website.

So if the registry wants payment for creating a domain, then no, there's no "trick" to making a company do something for free, short of hacking into their system – which is not recommended.

If you want free, there was one TLD which *did* give away domains for free (I think it was `.tk`), and there are a few places that give away subdomains (3rd-level domains) if you don't mind the extra dot.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access a domain name from any host worldwide, it has to be registered with a [registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar). This is what you pay for and there is no other way to make a domain name available to everyone on the internet.

The registrar has a number of responsibilities, one of which is making your domain name available through the global DNS system by registering the name server records of your domain, which point to the DNS servers that are authoritative for your domain. The registrar also verifies and records the "Whois" records for the domain.

The domain owner (you) can manage the DNS records for the domain on their own (publicly available) DNS servers, or can make use of commercially available DNS hosting services.

You can host DNS for a domain you have not registered (did not buy), on a DNS server that you host yourself, but you can't make it available globally, except by explicitly configuring clients with your DNS server(s).

Answer (score 0):

An unavailable domain can exist because somebody owns it and advertises
its presence on the global DNS on the internet.

It is available when the owner has put it up for sale.

You may from time to time happen upon websites with "interesting" names,
but when browsing to them you will only see an advertisement with
a link to the website of the vendor.

There is no way for you to "take over" such a domain-name, since it's
already registered by somebody else.

To "take over" a totally unused domain-name that you have invented,
you need to become an authorized registrar and supply your own
DNS server that will advertise this domain name.
It will be much much much cheaper to use an existing registrar for that.